# I want to make a bar with background color, in the bar is a text left aligned and a list right aligned

Tags: html, css

I want to create a bar with html. In the bar is a text left-aligned and a list right-aligned in the same line.

I tried to text align left and float the right list

I expect to have a bar like this

https://www.lidl-reisen.de/asfhdsfh
(at the top is that text "Lidl-Reisen.de - ... einfach urlaubiger!
Verantwortung Unternehmen Karriere Service & Hilfe"

```html
<header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="topbar">
      <p style="text-align: left">
        Lidl-Reisen.de - ... einfach urlaubiger!</p>
      <ul style="float: right">
        <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/verantwortung">Verantwortung</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/geschichte">Unternehmen</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/karriere">Karriere</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.lidl-reisen.de/faq">Service & Hilfe</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `display: flex` on `.topbar`, with the following additional settings:

```css
.topbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* to align the two children elements far left and right */
}

.topbar ul {
  margin: 0; /* to avoid the default margin causing a vertical offset */
}

.topbar ul li {
  display: inline-block; /* to display the li items next to each other */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="topbar">
    <span>Lidl-Reisen.de - ... einfach urlaubiger!</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/verantwortung">Verantwortung</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/geschichte">Unternehmen</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/karriere">Karriere</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.lidl-reisen.de/faq">Service & Hilfe</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flexbox with `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
.topbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <p>
    Lidl-Reisen.de - ... einfach urlaubiger!</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/verantwortung">Verantwortung</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/geschichte">Unternehmen</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/karriere">Karriere</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.lidl-reisen.de/faq">Service & Hilfe</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```